# Where I can find or generate build.gradle for Firebase in my react native expo application?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle, expo

I am working with npm expo and android studios, and I am trying to retrieve data from an exciting project in firebase. Thus I am following this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) .

when I was added to the project I had android studios installed already so I just installed expo and I was working on the app. I never needed the file build.Gradle, but now I need it for the firebase installation and I cant not find it.  when I open my project directory, I cant see anything about Gradle, and since I had never worked with expo I am wodeirng if I have to generate a build.gradle file or not? and if so how can I do that exactly, Also I am workign win 10.

===

I have added google-services.json to my app folder but I cant go any further since I cant find build.gradle!

Answer (score 6):

SO i figured it out, based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349213/react-native-android-app-build-gradle-file-missing), I was also missing the android folder, but then the solution was to do a

> expo eject

command in the cli and then it will make the android folder as well, and the I have access to build.gradle.